# network shares not showing up in finder osx Lion

Tags: osx-lion, netbios

The shares on my network are not showing after I tried this SMBup. I tried to follow this guide but things didn't turn up as I was expecting them to work.http://knowledgebase.hsti.com/re-installing-smb-on-mac-os-x-lion-10-7-x

This is the official website where in the middle of the page there is a note stating that "SMBUp installs Samba, which in turn replaces Apple’s OS X’s native netbios and SMB services. This means that while connecting to servers from the Finder remains functional, the Finder won’t be able to “browse” network services and servers from the network won’t show up in the Finder’s sidebar. Be advised."
http://eduo.info/apps/smbup

So i uninstall the samba restart the machine and now my shares don't show in the left side pane of finder. How can I get them back. Is the netbios service disabled

Answer (score 4):

I'm SMBUp's developer. I'm sorry I didn't see this post earlier, I would've been able to help.

As stated, Samba overrides Apple's own settings. If you decide to uninstall Samba these settings need to be re-enabled, but this can't be done programmatically. You need to go in and manually uncheck and re-check windows file sharing (SMB) in the sharing pane of system preferences a couple of times (to force the launchd scripts to be reinstated) and to go to the Network preference pane -> Advanced -> WINS and change your netbios name a couple of times and apply (also to "tickle" the daemons enough to have them start properly).